# Is it possible to refer to a classpath defined in one build file from another build file?

Tags: ant

In project A's build file, there is a `<path>`;

In project B's build file, I want to execute a tool class in project A by `<java>` task.

The `<java>` task need to use that path in its "classpathref" property.

The `<path>` in project A's build file is quite complicated so that I don't want to copy it to project B's build file.

So is it possible to refer to a classpath defined in one build file from another build file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) or [include](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html) ANT tasks is the way to do this.... however, these are both designed build multi-module builds. It's generally a really bad idea to couple two different projects in this manner....

I understand the motivation, classpath management is one of the most important and error-prone parts of a Java build. My recommendation is to adopt [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) and let it manage your build's 3rd party dependencies.

## Example:

The ivy [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task to create your ANT path, using dependency declarations.

```
   <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path">
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-simple" rev="1.6.4" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.10" conf="default"/>
    </ivy:cachepath>
```

The jars themselves can be locally stored or retrieved from the [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) repository

Comment: Project A's `<path>` (name: projectA.classpath) contains several `<fileset>`s pointing to lib directories and a plain text, `;` seperated property containing the compiling output dirs. Project A is our company's main project, which is really large. Project B is a auto benchmark system for project A, and we want to keep it small, simple and reduce the usage of third party libs. I need to use A's tool, but the tool needs A's "project.classpath" defined in A's build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Ant allows to [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) a project file into another.  You may check section 'Resolving files against the imported file' as this will be needed in most cases.