# Ant use Maven's library

Tags: java, maven, ant

I wrote a project which use maven. It's good for me.
But, some other people don't have maven, so I am trying to write an ant build.xml for them.

**My question is**:

Inside "javac" -> "classpath" tag, how could ant get the libs I used in the project from maven? So that could compile & pack all the 3rd-party libs into release via ant.

Is this possible or there are better solution for maven & ant exists in same project.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944349/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-a-classpath-defined-in-one-build-file-from-another-bu/10957899#10957899 and for more detailed ivy usage example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Use it to download your dependencies for ant from a maven repository.

Comment: I already use ivy in my project, it convert a pom.xml to ivy.xml first, then download jars via ivy.xml, really a good tool!

Answer (score 2):

Ant combined with Ivy is your answer. Ant can use a Maven repository to pull in jars, and can even be made to output a `pom.xml`, so the jar can be deployed back to a Maven repository.

I have an [ivy.dir](https://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir) project on Github that I use to help integrate Ivy into already existing Ant tasks -- especially if they use Subversion as a version control system. You can create a ivy.dir subproject, and make that an external on the Ant project.